# How to resume a program when logged in with different session

Tags: ssh, job-control, jobs

Here is the scenario:

Let's say that I log into my server via ssh and start an emacs or vi (or whatever other program) session. Then my ssh connection disconnects.

Is there a way for me to reconnect to those programs via a new ssh session.  In other words, when I log back into my server through a new ssh session?. In other words, how can I "pick up" where I left off.

I am assuming that programs are not automatically stopped when the first ssh account drops out...are they?

I read somewhere that I can use `screen` or `tmux`, I am wondering if there is a simple way, if not please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `screen`

Suppose you have logged in using SSH, then simply run following command to create screen session called 'mysession'

`screen -S mysession`

in case your connection disconnected, then you can simply attach your session using:

`screen -x mysession`

Check this [link](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/SCREEN) for more information about screen

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, using screen or tmux is the only way to accomplish this. I would definitely recommend tmux over screen, as tmux is a rewrite of screen which adds lots of convenient features.